# Error while accessing const char* in struct within a class

Tags: c++, embedded

I am using this snippet in one of my classes and I got a behavior, that I cannot explain properly. There are two different outputs, the one works on my simulation with the QtCreator, the other does not work on my embedded system.

**Header**:

```
typedef struct
{
    int anInt;
    const char* aString;
} aStruct;

class Foo
{
    ...

    private:

    ...

    static const aStruct STRUCT_ARRAY[];
    static const char* A_STRING;
    static const char* ANOTHER_STRING;
}
```

**CPP - Implementation**

```
const char* Foo::A_STRING   = "HelloStackOverflow";
const char* Foo::ANOTHER_STRING   = "ByeStackOverflow";

const aStruct Foo::STRUCT_ARRAY[] =
{
 { 0, A_STRING},
 { 1, ANOTHER_STRING}, 
};
```

If I want to access now the string within my class via `printf` the application crashes on my embedded machine (`printf(" ... %s ...", STRUCT_ARRAY[0].aString`). Using this in QtCreator with `qDebug << STRUCT_ARRAY[0].aString` it totally works fine.

It also works if I replace the const array entry directly with the string `A_STING` -> `"HelloStackOverflow"`. What am I missing here? In my understanding, the compiler just replaces the the entry within the array with the address the pointer points too.

I am using the Atmel AVR 32-bit toolchain.

/edit: it also crashes with `strcat` (besides the `printf` problem)

/edit2: what I tried so far (did not solve it yet)

- played around with the const-ness of the elements (especially of the array)
- Order of elements at the header
- Changed optimizer level (0|1|2|3|s)

Comment: How about adding \0 to A_STRING and ANOTHER_STRING

Comment: @o_weisman Character string literals already add `'\0'` automatically.

Comment: Do you have the code in the same cpp file as shown and in the correct order?

Comment: Try valgrind or `AddressSanitizer`. And it's C++, use `string`(`QString`) and so on. A MCVE would be helpful.

Comment: @n.m: The code is implemented in the order as shown. First the two strings are defined, followed up be the definition of the array.

Comment: @ black: the problem is not the behavior within Qt. I just cross tested it there to check whether the problem where also appears.
However, thanks for the reminder to AddressSanitizer and valgrind. Gonna test this later on.

Comment: Try swapping the order of declarations in class Foo. In theory it shouldn't matter but in practice things get broken. A compiler may mistakenly initialize in order of declaration instead of in order of definition, and whatnot.

Comment: @n.m. Unfortunately - as edited the original post - this does not solve the problem.